# Can not see full contents of dropdownlist qml

Tags: qt, drop-down-menu, combobox, qml

I use combobox in my application. I get trouble when the text of combobox is long. I can't see full content of some options. I want to see full content of text when drop down list open.

This is my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Rectangle{
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.topMargin: parent.height * 40 /100
        anchors.bottomMargin: parent.height * 40 /100
        anchors.leftMargin: parent.width * 40/100
        anchors.rightMargin: parent.width * 40/100
        ComboBox {
          model: ["hello", " text not full text not full"]
          font.pointSize: 20
        }
    }

}
```

When i click to combobox i just see "text not full text no..." instead of seeing "text not full text not full".

Answer (score 0):

Set a width for the `ComboBox` that is large enough for the largest text you expect to have. For example:

```
ComboBox {
    model: ["hello", " text not full text not full"]
    font.pointSize: 20
    width: 240
    anchors.centerIn: parent
}
```

If you want a more exact value, try `TextMetrics`:

```
ComboBox {
    id: comboBox
    model: ["hello", " text not full text not full"]
    font.pointSize: 20
    width: textMetrics.width
    anchors.centerIn: parent
}

// ...

TextMetrics {
    id: textMetrics
    text: "text not full text not full"
    font: comboBox.font
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work when i use two combobox in a Rowlayout. the width of combox can't be fixed. Is there any solution that we can see full content of text when drop down list appear? Can we make dropdownlist 's width be larger than combox 's width ?

Comment: OK... but your question wasn't in the context of a RowLayout. :) Anyway, in a layout you have to use the attached properties to set the size of items. In RowLayout that's Layout.preferredWidth or minimumWidth.

Comment: I found the solution for my issue. We just need to set popup.width = comboBox.width * 2